# MySQL is only saving a part of my encrypted password string from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, linq

I am passing in a string of somewhere over 300 characters (I'm unsure why it's so long I am using the built in `protect` method but that is not the issue) into my repository method to add it to the database. I pass it in like so:

`entities.Add(entity);
_Context.SaveChanges();`

Just over half of the string is then saved into MySql table and is obviously useless as it is only a part of what I need

> "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"

The string I want ^

The string i get

> QwBmAEQASgA4AEQATwBYAGcAUQBjAFIAdgB5ADUAQwB2AFkASwAwAE4AawB3AEoAdgA0AGcAUgAyADkAZgB6AHUAaABDAFcAbQBWAFkAbABqAHIASgBZAFEAZABhAG0ATQBvAHUAOQA2ADkASgBOAFIAMQAyAE0ASQBhADYARABuAFIAbQB5AEwAawBhADYALQBxAHkAVgBMAFYAbABwAFAANgBxAGEAQQBJAGYARQBXAHUASwBGAFgARAB2ADg

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the data limit for that field in your SQL table? (i.e. Varchar(250) will only save 250 characters, to store the entire password you will need to make sure the database column can store enough characters. Have you also limited the amount of characters it can receive in your db model?

Answer (score 0):

use `longtext` dataType

it will store your

> "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"

see this [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) for more details.

Comment: I have tried `LONGTEXT` and it makes no difference unfortunately